# Trouble with routing in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have tried to make a contact page. But the code did not work. Please help me to fix out it.......Route `get contact` work but when loading it shows error......

> Form

```
              <form method="POST" action="{{ route('postcontact') }}" >
```

> Route :

```
  Route::get('getcontact','ContactController@insertform');
  Route::post('postcontact','ContactController@insert');
```

> ```
> Controller :
> ```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\user\product;
use DB;

class ContactController extends Controller
{   

    public function insertform()
    {   
         return view('frontend.contact.create');
    }

   public function insert() 
   {      
      dd("Check"); exit;
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error please?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not assign route name for your post routing .
Try one of these solutions:
1.Try it in routing:

```
Route::post("/yoururl","controller@method")->name("postcontact");
```

2.Change your action in form tag:

```
<Form action="/yoururl" method="post">
```

By the way,dont forget `{{csrf_field()}}`.

Comment: As you say - it's most likely `csrf_field()`.

Comment: I am much oblige to you @akbar.

Comment: Adding `->name("postcontact")` to `Route::post("/yoururl","controller@method")->name("postcontact");` - `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('postcontact') }}" >` can stay as is.